# android-x86 on virtualbox and linux/windows

Tags: android, windows, virtualbox, android-x86

I have read that I can test android application on a emulator, but I could use also Virtualbox so the apps will be faster. 
Online there are many tutorials on Virtualbox, but it's indicated that I must select Linux on VirtualBox.
I Know that Android's kernel is a Linux Kernel 2.6, but the question is : Can I select also Windows? With Linux will be faster? It's a simple curiosity. x86 is the architecture and I think that I can use Linux, Windows or Mac OS X on Virtualbox.
Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for Android you need to select Linux, because underneath Android is Linux, it's not a matter of speed, it's a matter of how it was built.

remember that after you start the virtual machine you need to set the adb port in order to connect from your host OS:

```
 setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
 stop adbd
 start adbd
```

and then from your host OS:

```
  adb connect <IP_VIRTUALBOX_ANDROID>:5555
```

Comment: thank you SeRPRo , It was a stupid question :)
I understand now :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. and also welcome to SO